# fancybox resize - how/when to call the function

Tags: jquery, resize, fancybox

I have a fancybox with a form inside. If the form is incorrectly submitted, then errors appear on the form, which causes the height of the content to be bigger than the iframe, and I get scrollbars.

What I want is to resize the fancybox if there are errors (div.errors).

I have tried the $.fancybox.resize method but nothing seems to happen, but there is a good chance I'm just doing it wrong. Here is how I call the fancybox

```
$("#login").fancybox({
    'width': 682,
    'height': 295,
    'autoDimensions': true,
    'autoScale': true,
    'transitionIn': 'fade',
    'transitionOut': 'fade',
    'type': 'iframe'
});
```

I have sort of fixed it myself but I don't like the solution, I'd at least like to get the resize method working to see if it has the outcome I want. Here is the code I have to temporaily fix it

```
function resizeFancybox() {
    $('#fancybox-inner', top.document).height(500);
    $('#fancybox-wrap', top.document).height(500);
    $('iframe#fancybox-frame', top.document).css('height', '95%');
    parent.$.fancybox.center();     
}

if ($(".secure-login .errors").length){   
    resizeFancybox();
}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem solved? I just accidentally found out solution myself, just share if anyone come across the same problem as mine which took me half of day to figure it out.

```
function iWantResizeFancybox() {
     $.fancybox.update();//this function will re-size your fancybox (width&height)with content size inside your fancybox, if it exceeded size limit it will show scroll bar.
}
```